# Tag Excerpt is rendering with error

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here are two screenshots.
The first is Tag excerpt as it displays for me. Note there's only the last word rendered.
The second one is a tooltip for the same tag. Everything is fine.

[image: Tag Excerpt]
[image: Tag Excerpt Tooltip]

Is it a bug?
Environment: Windows7, Firefox v.3.6 *and* Chrome v.21. Attempted to use clean profiles for both to avoid any plug-ins clashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed cut the way you describe.

It looks like a little *too simplistic* heuristics here that cuts stuff prior to first "is" or "are".

I've seen this work well with *link-only-answers* tag at Meta Stack Overflow where it cuts off "answers that are" and displays excerpt as "barely more than a link to some URL".

Workaround is to reword tag wiki excerpt to something like:

> **salary is** how much someone is paid

Above should cut excerpt at first *is* but the remainder will look reasonable: "how much someone is paid".

I am calling this "workaround" though maybe it's the way how things are intended to work - searching through [tag-wiki-excerpt questions at MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-excerpt) did not bring me any information on that.

---

### update

[salary](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) wiki excerpt has been changed as proposed above, so that it is now rendered better:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVup.png]

Comment: **Good point; it seems to me that the above algorithm is** a total nonsense! :)